# Rails 3 render different partial using link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a project for a car dealer and in the car `show.html` I have photo gallery in the left side of the page and vehicle info in the right side. Vehicle info code is in a partial named `_vehicle_info` and gallery is in `_car_gallery` this is looking something like this:

```ruby
<div id="column-left">
    <%= render :partial => "car_gallery" %>
</div>
<div id="column-right">
    <%= render :partial => "vehicle_info" %>
</div>
```

In the `car_gallery` I can see only 12 photos of the car.

**The problem:**

What I want to do is to have a link near `car_gallery` div, and when the user clicks on it the partial `vehicle_info` in the left side will be replaced by the partial `car_gallery_all` (this partial contains all the photos for that car, not limited to 12). 
Is there any short way to do this? Please help.

Comment: This is a javascript thing. I added jQuery Tag to your question. What you need to to is replacing the content of a div this can be done easy using jQuery.

Comment: Do you want to accomplish this without a page refresh?

Comment: yes, without refresh.. jquery tabs would be one solution, but I am looking for another way if there is one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit due to lack of rep:**

This will work in rails 3.1, not sure about 3.0 or below..

Also, davidb's answer would, if I understand it correctly, load *all* of the images regardless of whether the user wants to view them or not - this solution would only load them if the user clicks on the link to view them..

..............................................................................

## controller

```
                def all_car_photos
                  ...
                  respond_to do |format|
                     format.js
                  end
                end
```

## view

```
            <div id="column-left">
                <%= render :partial => "car_gallery" %>
            </div>
            <div id="column-right">
                <%= render :partial => "vehicle_info" %>
            </div>
            <%= link_to "Show All Photos", path_to_controller_action(@car), { :method => :get, :remote => true} %>
```

## all_car_photos.js.erb

```
            $('#column-right').html("<%= escape_javascript(render "car_gallery_all") %>");
```

Ok so, the view contains the link_to method which points to the all_car_photos controller action. The key thing here is that the link_to contains :remote => true - this submits the request using the baked in Rails AJAX functionality.

The controller action does what it needs to do, but responds with the .js view - all_car_photos.js.erb - This contains a line of jQuery which will replace the content of the 'column-right' div with the 'car_gallery_all' partial..

It's late, but that setup should work..

Comment: I am trying your example and I'll see the results. I'll get back with "answer accept" when I'll get the job done. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. That's not copy/paste code though.. It'll need tweaking but the general idea will get you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Add the link and give an id to it. You use the "#" because it does not link to anything effectifly.

```
<%= link_to "my link text", "#", :id => "replace_vehicle_info" %>
```

Then you add some jQuery to your `public/javascript/application.js` (I except you use rails 3 not 3.1 because your question is tagged like that) to replace the content of that div.

```
$("#replace_vehicle_info").click(function() {
     $("#vehicle_info").replaceWith(<your html here>)
})
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try this as an alternative for FiveOhOne asnwer.